# Is there a function or method to compare if two strings are similar (not perfectly equal) in PHP?

Tags: php

In PHP there are several functions or methods to compare the equality between two strings. For example `"Hello world" == "Hello world"`. But let's say that I have strings that are *almost* equal. Can these be compared and like get a value of similarity (i.e. 97% are equal).

```
<?php
$a = "Stack Overflow";
$b = "Stack-Overflow";
$result = str_compare_similarities($a, $b); // should return something like 0.958 for example
?>
```

I don't think that there's a function for this in PHP (or is there?). MySQL has for instance the function `FULLTEXT` that compares how much two strings are equal. But can it be solved with PHP?

Comment: Try this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Ah, great @FaizanKhalid! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**similar_text** — Calculate the similarity between two strings

Description

```
similar_text(string $string1, string $string2, float &$percent = null): int
```

This calculates the similarity between two strings as described in Programming Classics: Implementing the World's Best Algorithms by Oliver (ISBN 0-131-00413-1). Note that this implementation does not use a stack as in Oliver's pseudo code, but recursive calls which may or may not speed up the whole process. Note also that the complexity of this algorithm is O(N**3) where N is the length of the longest string.

For more info [click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)